# Execute a method on multiply variables with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter

I have a multiply variables with similar names (button1, button2, button3 ... etc)
I trying to make a button that every time that the user hit him the text from all the buttons (and on other cases of specific part of them) will be wiped.

My code is look like that:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

def reset():
   pass

button1 = ttk.Button(root, text="bla")
button2 = ttk.Button(root, text="bla")
button3 = ttk.Button(root, text="bla")
button4 = ttk.Button(root, text="bla")
button5 = ttk.Button(root, text="bla")
button6 = ttk.Button(root, text="bla")
button7 = ttk.Button(root, text="bla")
button8 = ttk.Button(root, text="bla")
button9 = ttk.Button(root, text="bla")

reset_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Restart", command=lambda: reset())

root.mainloop()
```

Now I tried to create a generator that create a multi line to execute with **for** loop without any success.
I know that I can do something like that:

```
def reset():
    button1.config(text="")
    button2.config(text="")
    button3.config(text="")
    button4.config(text="")
    ...
```

but it seem really unpythonic way to do that + on other part of the code I need a dynamic buttonX.config...

Someone have an idea how can I do this?

Comment: Use a *container* to keep your `buttons` and *loop through the container*.

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating variables with numeric suffixes like that, you should be using a list or array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply loop over your buttons (as already pointed out in the comments):

```
def reset():
    for button in [button1, button2, ..., button9]:
        button.config(text="")
```

If you can you may want to create the buttons directly as part of a list. That may or may not be possible. What I mean is something like:

```
buttons = [ttk.Button(root, text="bla"),
           ttk.Button(root, text="bla"),
           ttk.Button(root, text="bla"),
           ttk.Button(root, text="bla"),
           ttk.Button(root, text="bla"),
           ttk.Button(root, text="bla"),
           ttk.Button(root, text="bla"),
           ttk.Button(root, text="bla"),
           ttk.Button(root, text="bla")]

def reset():
    for button in buttons:
        button.config(text="")
```

Comment: Your list contains only one item. Can you edit to show how to create more items?

Comment: Alright, today I create a list with all the buttons inside it and call them by they index number, it's work great! Thank you